# Compare two values per row on multiple rows

Tags: jquery

I am stuck with the each function. Could someone please help me getting on the right track? Here is my code so far and an image to visualize what I am trying to achieve.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXGQQ.png)

Thank you very much!

```
    $('.ui-button').on('mouseenter', function () { // just for testing

        var c = 1; // skip first row

        var eventdate = $('.ui-sortable tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) .InputfieldDatetimeDatepicker').attr('value');
        var eventtime = $('.ui-sortable tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) .uk-select option:selected').text();


        $('.ui-sortable tr').each(function () {
            c++;

            var eventdate = $('.ui-sortable tr:nth-child(' + [c] + ') > td:nth-child(1) .InputfieldDatetimeDatepicker').attr('value');
            var eventtime = $('.ui-sortable tr:nth-child(' + [c] + ') > td:nth-child(2) .uk-select option:selected').text();

            if (eventdate === eventtime) { // ?
                $(this).addClass('error');
            }

            console.log('eventdate: ' + eventdate + ', eventtime: ' + eventtime);

        });


    });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for my poor description. It's the combination of field one and two – these values should only appear once in the table. My goal is to show all duplicates via a class, so that the user can see where the double entries are and can correct date and time per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle code: When something is changed, then it is checked all rows!

```
    $(function () {
  
    $('.ui-sortable tr').on('change', function (e) {
    
    $('.ui-sortable tr').each((i, tr)=>{
        $(tr).attr('no', i);
      $(tr).attr('class', '');
    });
    
    $('.ui-sortable tr').each((i, tr)=>{
    
        let foundDuplicates = false;
        let no = $(tr).attr('no');
      let date = $(tr).children('td:nth-child(1)').children('input').val();
      let time = $(tr).children('td:nth-child(2)').children('select').val();
    
      $('.ui-sortable tr').each((i, tr_)=>{
      
        let no_ = $(tr_).attr('no');
        if(no === no_) return false;
        
        let date_ = $(tr_).children('td:nth-child(1)').children('input').val();
        let time_ = $(tr_).children('td:nth-child(2)').children('select').val();
        if((date === date_) && (time === time_)){
          $(tr).attr('class', 'error');
          $(tr_).attr('class', 'error');
          foundDuplicates = true;
        }
      });
      
      if(foundDuplicates){
        $(tr).attr('class', 'error');
      }
      
    });
    
  });
        
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your approach is quite helpful. Please read my more detailed description above I just posted to understand what I want to achieve. Grateful to your kind help.

Comment: Hi, if you make a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/ then post the link here, then I could help yoi direct within that code!

Comment: Thank you again for your help! Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmsHH/4ed7v8na/23/). If the first and second entries equal, mark every occurence with the class 'error', because a date/time can only show one event.

Comment: Hi, I changed your code in the fiddle! I paste the code in new answer!

Comment: I edited my answer and appended the fiddle code

Comment: Perfect, thank you sooo much! It works like a charme 